# how to use exit or continue program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this code but my instructor said that the program should loop for new input until told to stop by the person running the program.

> *hint: an input of zero (0) kilometers could be used to stop the program.

Can someone show me how to include that in my code? I used `x=raw_input()`, since it closes so fast in cmd when I ran the program.

```
def kilo():
    kilometers = input("Please enter a distance in kilometers?:") 
    return kilometers

def miles(km):
   """calculates miles from kilometers km""" 
   miles = km * 0.6214
   return miles    

def main():
  print "This program converts kilometers to miles." 
  km = kilo()
  print miles(km) 

  main()

 x= raw_input()
```

Comment: @Yann: the homework tag is deprecated (see the link on the "Community Bulletin" notes on the right side of the page).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `main()` routine.

Instead of `def main():`, you can use a `while True:` loop. And if `km` happens to be returned as `0`, you could `break` out of the loop:

```
if km==0:
    break
```

Also, better be explicit and use `kilometers = float(raw_input("Please enter..."))`.

Comment: ok so if I dont declare to stop the program will run in the loop right?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "declare", but generally, yes, that's the idea.

Comment: like my instructor expected my program to run ask user if they want to run the program again if yes "please enter yes" if not please enter no" so I was trying to figure out how to use that will my code

Comment: But your instructor also gave you a hint about how you could stop the program. You might want to add this in the `raw_input()` prompt, so the user knows what to do...